# Convexity Adjustment on sensitivity computation for Futures

Tags: convexity, yield-futures

Convexity adjustment is a correction term that helps in deriving futures price from forward price and vice versa. But, will this convexity adjustment come into play when we are trying to compute sensitivities for IR Future contracts (the Delta and the Gamma). Do IR futures have Gamma at all?